# How to read/write via API to Excel Online without requiring an business or school account tenant

Tags: python, excel, console-application, microsoft-graph-api

I want to write via console-based Python script to a workbook in Excel Online using a "normal" Microsoft Account (e.g `john.doe@outlook.com`). No O365 or other subscriptions are involved.

I checked the MS Docs and every article points to the Microsoft Graph API.

E.g.

- [MSFT Web Python Tutorial](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/47864a4e87798e7199319fde2636462ad60864af/get-started/python-excel.md)
- [MSFT Console Python Tutorial](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python-sample-console-app)

If I try to access the graph with my personal account, the API will return the error message:

```
'Tenant does not have a SPO license.'
```

Do I miss another way how to interact with Excel Online / OneDrive using a normal MSA?

Comment: I could be mistaken, but based on your comments/documentation, it would seem that the API does not support this use-case. You're essentially asking the question: "I don't have credentials to do *X*, how can I do *X* while using my credentials?"

Comment: @DavidZemens yes. But I thought that my use case is so obvious that I must overlooked something.